# How to use edit update detelte function in grails table format

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-plugin

i have to show user list in a table format with basic functionality in a grail app, please give me a link or provide details what method or controls i needs to use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please explain what you're trying to achieve in better detail.

Comment: i wanted to complete crud functionality with list of users data displayed a table format, the problem is i have no i idea how to pass values between controller and .gsp  page. clicked user details id and other things.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scaffolding, which will do just that for you.

Here's your link:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/16.%20Scaffolding.html

Comment: Based on the subject, I think he's looking for inline editing, which scaffolding doesn't do.

Comment: i want to write my one actions not through scaffholding true.

Comment: why not just use scaffolding to generate actions in controller and modify views to suit your needs?